# How to maintain state with GlassFish4 Socket Server?

Tags: java, sockets, glassfish, server

I am **building a game using a socket server via `GlassFish` 4**.

The problem I'm running into is that,

**every time a socket connection is made my @ServerEndpoint class is re-instantiated**.

I'm basically just looking for the class that kicks off the `GlassFish` 4 server similar to writing a Servlet in `Tomcat`.  I just need a place to **initialize the state of my game**, I thought the **server end-point** would be that place, but **it's re-initializing my game state** every time I open a connection to it (which is obviously problematic).

I could write my game state containers as **singletons** or **static classes with static initializers**, but I would **like to avoid both** of those things and **instantiate all** of my game state containers in, I guess **the class that sits listening for the web socket connections**?

I haven't been able to find something like that in the glassfish tutorials I have read through.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this.  I was not declaring my data structures with "static final".  Doing just "private HashMap<> x;" resulted in "x" being reinstantiated every time a new connection was opened.

"private static final HashMap<> x;" looks like it stopped it from doing this.